# Why mongodb on production is using local computer connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-admin

I am developing a react-admin site and using mongodb. When I uploaded files to the server, it seems that production version on server is using my local computer mongodb connection. This is my connection string: `mongodb://localhost:27017/my-collection`
If I try to access a site from my computer, it works, because it uses local computer connection, if I try to access it from phone , it does not works, only shows `Could not connect to the server`

Site is served by `nginx` and run with `pm2`

Can somebody help? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the term localhost refers to the local machine (where the app is running) - if running on your computer, localhost refers to your computer.  If running on the server, localhost refers to the server.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @blurfus I know that, No it does not answer my question. that is the thing that 'localhost' on server should refer to server mongodb instance, but instead it refers to my localmashine server, which is very weird

Comment: And Yes, mongodb is running on the server too

Comment: Are you sure that "server" in the error message refers to the MongoDB server? It sounds more like a problem with nginx than MongoDB. Or the web site has web URLs pointing to localhost so it actually loads the local dev page.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Site is working on local mashine, but on phone only sign in page in presented, And when I try to log in it says: 'Could not connect to the server' as an alert message. So if sign in page is working, means site is loaded itself.

Comment: question is not clear.  can you provide more details? How do you access the application from browser vs from phone?

Comment: I access the site in browser the same way from both places: mydomain.com

Comment: Did you change the react-admin's data provider to point to the server's domain? In any case this doesn't have anything to do with MongoDB setup.

Comment: It has an api url http://localhost:3001

Comment: ...well that's obviously wrong. It connects to the local dev server (which isn't running on the phone.) You need to change it to the address where it's running on the server.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, after changing that, now it works as expected! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had to change url in react-admin dataProvider. it had `localhost:3001`, but I had to changed it to `myDomain.com:3001`